# Multiple Audio Sources for Audio Spectrum

Tags: after-effects

how can I have more than 1 audio source at the same time for the Audio Spectrum effect of After Effects? Thank you.

I'm using After Effects.

(I tried to upload an image, but it there is an error)

Answer (score 1):

Place your multiple audio sources into a comp, then place that comp into the comp where your audio spectrum effect is going to be.  Point the Audio Spectrum effect at the comp with your multiple layers within it, and they should all affect it together.
[image]
[image]